# Adding a song file to iTunes via the command line without playing the file

Tags: itunes, command-line, unix

I want to add song files to iTunes via the command line.

```
    open -a iTunes -g song.mp3
```

does exactly this. - However it starts *playing* the song, too. Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder for that (see [PH19617](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19617)):

```
cp song.mp3 ~/"Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes/"
```

If iTunes is running, anything you copy into this folder will be imported into iTunes automatically (and deleted from the folder afterwards).

Please note:

- The folder name might be language specific, so check the name on your system first.
- Depending on when iTunes was installed, the media folder may be called either `iTunes Media` or `Tunes Music`

Comment: You should use `mv` instead of `cp` so that the file is added and you are not left with a duplicate song file outside of your iTunes library.

Comment: Not only does the "Automatically add to iTunes" folder simply not work in many instances, it doesn't work for a distributed library.

Comment: Support for distributed libraries isn't part of the question here. But you are correct: if you distribute your iTunes library across several disks neither "Add to iTunes" nor dragging media files into the iTunes window will import in a useable way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use applescript to do so and there's much more to explore. (add music to special playlist, etc.)

for example, you need to add file /User/username/myMusic/my.mp3 to lib, create a script file named add.scpt

```
tell application "iTunes"
    add alias ((path to home folder as string) & "myMusic:my.mp3") 
end tell
```

run command:

```
osascript add.scpt
```